# Не работает find в linux

Tags: linux, shell

Есть 2 debian-сервера (пакеты на обоих одинаковые и версии 8.4) с find 4.4.2.
Почему-то на одном `find / -iname *her*` ищет всё независимо от регистра, а на втором - не ищет. Почему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Краткий ответ - нужно в кавычки брать. То есть, писать так

```
find / -iname "*his*"
```

Почему так происходит? просто баш выдит звездочку и пытается размернуть шаблон. И на втором сервере случайно так произошло, что нашелся каталог/файл, который подходит по имени. То есть, если маска `"*his*"` и есть файл 'tohis.txt`, то вышеприведенная команда просто превратиться в

```
find / -iname "tohis.txt"
```

и будет искать указанный файл. А есть ли он - кто его знает.

Comment: Действительно, работает. Хм, но я не могу понять, почему он на одном сервере ищет без ковычек, а на втором - нет :(

Comment: Покажите вывод ls / на каждом сервере - укажу причину. И точную маску, которую используете для поиска.

Comment: Вообще я искал перловый модуль curl вот тут: `find /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/auto/WWW/Curl/ -iname *curl*` и там он есть - Curl.so , но почему-то find его не видит если не указывать ковычки...

Comment: @user212017, *а на втором - нет* — потому что в том каталоге, где вы выполняете эту команду, присутствует файл/каталог, имя которого соответствует регулярному выражению `*her*` (т.е., имя содержит строку `her`).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin со звездочками - это не регулярное выражение.

Comment: @KoVadim, можно не только кавычки использовать (как двойные, так и одинарные), но и «заэскейпить» метасимволы: `\*his\*`.

Comment: Все можно. Главное понимать разницу между кавычками:) а то можно ещё такого получить.... ух!

Comment: @KoVadim, *со звездочками - это не регулярное выражение* — если строка выглядит как регулярное выражение и ведёт себя как регулярное выражение, то, я думаю, её вполне можно назвать регулярным выражением.

Comment: это не регулярное выражение. звездочка в начале - это неверное регулярное выражение. Данная конструкция в английсом называется "pattern" - по русски видимо - шаблоны. Хотя часто употребляется и "маска".

Comment: Ребята, на обоих серверах в директрии /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/auto/WWW/Curl/ есть только файл Curl.so . Но почему-то на одном я могу его найти find'ом, а на втором - нет. И пока я не могу понять почему так...

Comment: есть много вариантов. К примеру, на одном bash, а на другом dash или zsh. Или алиас проиписан.

Comment: @KoVadim, как я уже упоминал, пакеты одинаковые. На обоих только bash, алиасов нет... вроде бы >_>

Comment: придумал. Шаблон разворачивается с **текущего каталога**. У Вас в текущем каталоге есть файл, который попадает под шаблон. сделайте переход в пустой каталог и сравните.

Comment: @KoVadim , гениально! Если перейти, например, в тот же /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/auto/WWW/Curl/ и оттуда выполнить `find /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.20/auto/WWW/Curl/ -iname *curl*` - всё работает! А я, дурак, голову ломал, что за фигня... спасибо большое! Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, как-то более развёрнуто объяснить это явление в своём ответе выше? Возможно даже со ссылками на RTFM :) буду признателен!

Comment: @KoVadim, [In theoretical computer science and formal language theory, a regular expression (sometimes called a rational expression) is a sequence of characters that define a search pattern, mainly for use in pattern matching with strings, or string matching, i.e. "find and replace"-like operations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). по-моему, под **такое** определение shell pathname expansion вполне подпадает: тот же самый *pattern matching*, конечно, более примитивный, и с синтаксисом… (продолжение следует).

Comment: … существенно отличающимся как от закреплённых в posix-овых стандартах bre и ere, так и от стандартов де-факто типа pcre.

Answer (score 1):

> а на втором - не ищет. Почему?

вероятно потому, что на втором сервере в том каталоге, из которого вы запускаете команду, присутствует один файл или каталог, имя которого соответствует указанному вами шаблону `*her*`.

для того, чтобы этого избежать, надо:

- либо экранировать мета-символы (`*`, `?`, `[`) с помощью обратного слэша: `\*her\*`
- либо заключить весь параметр в кавычки (лучше — одинарные): `'*her*'`

---

проиллюстрирую наглядно работу т.н. механизма *pathname expansion*, который реализован в любой posix-совместимой оболочке.

1. создадим пустой каталог и сделаем его текущим:

   ```
   $ mkdir /tmp/test; cd /tmp/test
   ```
2. посмотрим, что сделает оболочка с параметром `*her*` в такой ситуации:

   ```
   $ echo *her*
   *her*
   ```

   как видим, никаких преобразований сделано не было — параметр был передан программе *echo* (если быть точнее, то, скорее всего, внутренней команде оболочки, но в данном случае это несущественно) «как есть».
3. создадим файл, содержащий строку `her` в названии:

   ```
   $ touch father
   ```
4. и повторим ту же команду:

   ```
   $ echo *her*
   father
   ```

   как видим, параметр `*her*` превратился в параметр `father`!
5. а если создать ещё несколько файлов, содержащих в именах строку `her`:

   ```
   $ touch here motherland
   ```
6. то один параметр превратится вообще в несколько:

   ```
   $ echo *her*
   father here motherland
   ```

в вашем случае произошло примерно то же самое — параметр `*her*` программы *find* превратился в совсем другой параметр, представляющий какое-то имя (содержащее строку `her`) файла или каталога, наличествующего в том каталоге, где вы запускали свою команду.

---

доп. чтение:

- [posix: pathname expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_06)
- [bash: filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion)